# Creating a new level for one index in a multiindex when using groupby and apply

Tags: python, pandas

I am working in Python3 / Pandas. I have a DataFrame with a multiindex: data source ('src'), date ('dt'), and status ('stat'). There is an arbitrary measurement column called 'val'. Currently, there are three levels to the 'status' index (`['gain', 'loss', 'current']`). I want to create  fourth level, 'net', which will reflect the difference between the 'gain' level and the 'loss' level for all measurements/ columns (currently only val, b/c that's the only column in this example). I would call this new 'stat' level 'net'.

**I could think of solutions that would widen the DataFrame, but this is undesirable when the original DataFrame contains many measurement columns.** This is the case for my actual data set, even though that's not reflected in this example. **So an answer should generalize to many measurement columns, not just the `'val'` column in the example `df`.**

Here is my current attempt:

```
from datetime import datetime
import random as rd
import pandas as pd

# create the levels for the multiindex
u_source = ['src1','src2']
u_date = pd.date_range(end=datetime.today(), freq='1D', periods=3).date
u_status = ['current','gain','loss']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [u_source, u_date, u_status],
    names = ['src', 'dt', 'stat']
)

# create the measurement values
rd.seed(42)
vals = [rd.randint(0,9) for _ in range(len(idx))]
vals2 = [rd.randint(0,9) for _ in range(len(idx))]

# create the dataframe from the multiindex
# and measurement values
df = pd.DataFrame({'val':vals, 'val2':vals2}, index=idx)

# function to create measurement values that
# reflect differences in vals between 
# two levels of a particular index in a multiindex
# Operates on a groupby object
def get_net(gb):
    new = gb.loc[(slice(None),slice(None),'gain'), :]
    new.rename(index={'gain':'net'}, inplace=True)
    lost = gb.loc[(slice(None),slice(None),'loss'), :]
    lost.rename(index={'loss':'net'}, inplace=True)

    nn = new - lost
    # pd.merge(gb, nn, how='outer') # doesn't work
    return nn # doesn't recombine with other levels, creates extra columns



# group by src and dt
# per each source and date,
# take the difference in val 
# between stat=gain and stat=loss, 
# label that difference as stat=net
df_gb = df.groupby(['src','dt']) # groupby
ans = df_gb.apply(get_net) # apply func to gb
ans
```

[image]

I can perform the calculation. However, there are two undesirable aspects to my current output. First, the two indices of the multiindex used in the groupby, 'src' and 'dt', are duplicated in the output multiindex. Second, I still want the 'val' column for the original indices ... but the original levels of 'stat' ('gain', 'loss', 'current') were all dropped in the output.

How do I prevent duplication of indices in the multiindex, and retain all the original index levels and associated values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Per comments below.

You need `as_index = False` as a parameter to `groupby`:

```
df_gb = df.groupby(['src','dt'], as_index=False)
```

## Alternative way..

More robust and generic code:

```
df.unstack().stack(0).eval('net = gain - loss').unstack().stack(0)
```

IIUC, do you want something like this:

```
df.unstack()['val'].eval('net = gain - loss').stack().to_frame(name='value')
```

Output:

```
                         value
src  dt         stat          
src1 2019-06-12 current      1
                gain         0
                loss         4
                net         -4
     2019-06-13 current      3
                gain         3
                loss         2
                net          1
     2019-06-14 current      1
                gain         8
                loss         1
                net          7
src2 2019-06-12 current      9
                gain         6
                loss         0
                net          6
     2019-06-13 current      0
                gain         1
                loss         3
                net         -2
     2019-06-14 current      3
                gain         8
                loss         9
                net         -1
​
```

Comment: the output format of the index is correct, but does this generalize to when there are many measurement columns (e.g., val1, val2, ..., valN instead of just val)? E.g., I can't just delete `['val']` and have the code run (obviously ... but that slice is the problem). I mentioned this condition in my question, but I'll make an edit to bold it. Very close though, thank you for taking a stab at it!

Comment: Away fron computer now, but you can unstack then stack. level zero and use the same merhod for many vals.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I edited my question so that the test case was more suitable for testing answers that tried to generalize to many columns. If you want, you can edit our copied output to show that your output works for two measurement columns. Thanks for the answe!

Comment: Side question though ... is there something I was doing wrong with `apply`? I'm not sure that the `eval()` approach would work for more complicated functions ... :(

Comment: The eval approach will not work some complicated situations such as column names with a space and etc... However, we should be able to do an apply.   I will look at it and see.

Comment: Use `as_index=False`  like this `df_gb = df.groupby(['src','dt'], as_index=False)`

Comment: Oh wow, that last comment solves all my problems! I already accepted your answer, but that last comment really is the simplest answer to my question (given what I'd already written). That was my mistake, thank you for detecting it, and for showing my an alternate approach with stack/unstack.